# Save and Load Coroutines state

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new in Unity.
Is it possible to save the current state of coroutine and load it then continue the coroutine?
I have a few coroutines in my project and i want to save it all.

Comment: When you say save and load a coroutine, do you mean in the same game instance, or to have the state saved when a player quits a game, then have it load when they come back?

Comment: the second one, save the state and load it when they comeback.

Comment: You need to do it inside the coroutine storing any value or flags that help you to control state.

Comment: You don't save Coroutines .. as little as you would save a Method ... you save **values** => fields and properties.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question? If any below was helpful, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/405359) to give the answerer some reputation points and help others browsing the search panel see that there is a helpful answer here.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a Coroutine, eg;

```cs
using System.Collections;
public class C {
    private void before() { }
    private void after() { }
    public IEnumerator MyCoroutine()
    {
        before();
        yield return null;
        after();
    }
}
```

The compiler defines a new type to track the state of the method, including any local variables. You can see that in action by using a [decompiler](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQDABCCMB0DCB7ANsgpgYwC4EtEDsBnAbgFgAoEAZigCYJ4IBvCiNiABwCccA3AQyxooAFggAjNADNEXNAAoAlMwgBfVu259BwkGP5ShXJSvXl2UGgEkAovgCuAWzRdBsiAFkAnki6J7uPgKihpsLOYW7JIyckpkEZFQ0NBQAOwQDqjxiWwGRnGhahSqQA).

While it's more work, and more complicated, you could implement your own `IEnumerable` types instead.

```cs
public class MyCoroutine : IEnumerator
{
    private int state = 0;
    public object Current { get; private set; }

    private void before() { }
    private void after() { }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        switch (state)
        {
            case 0:
                before();
                state++;
                Current = null;
                return true;
            case 1:
                after();
                state++;
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void Reset() => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

Then it's up to you how you wish to save / load and resume your coroutines.

Answer (score 0):

Unity doesn't have anything built in to support this. So, let's go over what saving a coroutine entails.

A started & incomplete coroutine has local variables, a yield instruction that they are currently at. And the yield that they are currently at may instantiate an anonymous  `YieldInstruction`.

So, if you would want to save a coroutine, you would need to save these things. So, you would need to save a bunch of locals as well as answer the question of how to resume the couroutine at the correct yield instruction. This is a complicated task, and the outcome would probably be very messy without substantial effort and refactoring.

So, I recommend that you accept the fact you will need to do some refactoring. Rather than keeping the coroutines intact, the more straightforward path here is to "unroll" your coroutines into the various update methods:

- `Update`, when using `yield return null`, `WaitForSeconds`, `WaitUntil`, `WaitForSecondsRealtime`
- `FixedUpdate`, if using the uncommonly used `WaitForFixedUpdate`
- `LateUpdate`, when using `WaitForEndOfFrame`

and move the locals of the coroutine into fields, as well as any additional necessary fields needed to track time passage in place of `WaitForSeconds` and such. And to make these fields so that they serialize properly.

Since there is no specific example given in the question, I will provide a before/after example that may help:

#### Using Coroutine (state not serializable):

```
void Update()
{
    DoStuff();
}

void StartMoveTowards(Transform target, Vector3 destination, float duration)
{
    StartCoroutine(DoMoveTowards(target, destination, duration));
}

IEnumerator DoMoveTowards(Transform target, Vector3 destination, float duration)
{
    float v = Vector3.Distance(target.position, destination) / duration;
    while( target.position != destination)
    {
        yield return null;
        target.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(target.position, destination, v * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    DoFirstThing();
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    DoSecondThing();
}
```

#### Not using coroutine (serializable state):

```
enum MoveTowardsState 
{
    NotRunning,
    Starting,
    MovingTowards, 
    DoingFirstThing,
    Waiting
}

// serializable coroutine locals, timers, and instruction state
[SerializeField] MoveTowardsState currentMoveTowardsState;
[SerializeReference] 
[SerializeField] Transform moveTowardsTarget;
[SerializeField] Vector3 moveTowardsDestination;
[SerializeField] float moveTowardsDuration;
[SerializeField] float waitT;
[SerializeField] float v;

void Update()
{
    DoStuff();
    HandleDoMoveTowards();
}

void StartMoveTowards(Transform target, Vector3 destination, float duration)
{
    moveTowardsTarget = target;
    moveTowardsDestination = destination;
    moveTowardsDuration = duration;
    currentMoveTowardsState = MoveTowardsState.Starting;
}

void HandleDoMoveTowards()
{
    bool continuing = true;
    while(continuing)
    {
        continuing = false;
        switch (currentMoveTowardsState)
        {
            case MoveTowardsState.NotRunning: 
                break;

            case MoveTowardsState.Starting:
                v = Vector3.Distance(target.position, destination) / duration;
                if (target.position != destination)
                {
                    currentMoveTowardsState = MoveTowardsState.MovingTowards;
                }
                else 
                {
                    currentMoveTowardsState = MoveTowardsState.DoingFirstThing;
                    continuing = true;
                }
                break;

            case MoveTowardsState.MovingTowards:
                target.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(moveTowardsTarget.position, 
                        moveTowardsDestination, v * Time.deltaTime);

                if (target.position == destination)
                { 
                    currentMoveTowardsState = MoveTowardsState.DoingFirstThing;
                    continuing = true;
                }
                break;
            
            case MoveTowardsState.DoingFirstThing:
                DoFirstThing();
                waitT = 3f;
                currentMoveTowardsState = MoveTowardsState.Waiting;
                break;
  
            case MoveTowardsState.Waiting:
                waitT -= Time.deltaTime;
                if (waitT <= 0f)
                {
                    DoSecondThing();
                    currentMoveTowardsState = MoveTowardsState.NotRunning;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And if multiple parallel instances are needed, You can create a new monobehavior for the coroutine, and create an instance for each running instance.

Note: I can't check syntax at the moment, so please mind any syntax errors. Hopefully the idea gets across. Please let me know in the comments if any parts dont make sense.

Comment: You don't tag an `enum` with `[Serializable]` ;) I'm pretty convinced OP doesn't really mean to store the coroutine `yield` state but rather the values that are changed by the routine ... so I think simply use some value class (or directly fields in the MonoBehaviour) and serialize it (JSON) would be enough

Comment: I would repeat what the C# compiler is doing for free, and write a serialisable `IEnumerator`. Basically what you did, but in the `MoveNext()` method, with some `static IEnumerator Resume(..)` that tells unity to start the coroutine with the saved state.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman actually, that's a great idea. I actually have to log off for the night so I wont be able to write that up until later. I can @ you later if you want when I get the edit in.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman I don't think I can do that justice, do you think you could write another answer or edit this one? I'll upvote it if you make another answer and @ me